# Select first drop down then display second drop down

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in javascript. I hope someone could help me with my question. I wanted my form to display another drop down once the first drop down is selected. The second drop down depends on which option is selected in the first drop down. Thanks!

```
<body>
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input01">Select</label>
        <div class="controls"> 
          <select name="client_orderid" id="options" onchange="showText()">
          <option value="A"> A</option>
          <option value="B"> B</option>
          <option value="C"> C</option>
            </select> <br>

            <div class="control-group" id="showA" style="display:none;">
            <select name="client_orderid" id="options" onchange="showText()">
              <option value="blue"> blue</option>
              <option value="green"> green</option>
              <option value="yellow"> yellow</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group" id="showB" style="display:none;">
            <select name="client_orderid" id="options" onchange="showText()">
              <option value="sun"> sun</option>
              <option value="sky"> sky</option>
              <option value="tree"> tree</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group" id="showC" style="display:none;">
            <select name="client_orderid" id="options" onchange="showText()">
              <option value="dog"> dog</option>
              <option value="cat"> cat</option>
              <option value="fish"> fish</option>
            </select>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried which didn't work.

Comment: what you tried so far??

Comment: Why dont you use jQuery ? Do you like to write 100 statements for same task that can be done in 4,5 lines? Check here -> http://blogs.learnnowonline.com/2012/10/03/7-benefits-of-jquery/

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com—"100 statements"? Really?

Comment: Not really , I mean if lots of things (features and code) is well built and tested in jQuery , why reinvent the wheel ?

Answer (score 1):

Initially , display only 1st Dropdown hide others.

So on change of 1st show 2nd like

```
$("#1stDropdown").change(function(){
    $("#2nsDropdown").show();
});
```

and so on

Comment: I think you missed "*…The second drop down depends on which option is selected in the first drop down*", i.e. that the select element displayed should be based on the value selected in the first select.

Answer (score 0):

Some points to correct-

1-Put second dropdown hidden by default and display it on change of 1st dropdown.

2-Also call different function onchange of different select.

3-Id of all elements should be unique. If you want it to be same, use class instead

```
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input01">Select</label>
        <div class="controls"> 
          <select name="client_orderid" id="options1" onchange="showTexColor()">
          <option value="A"> A</option>
          <option value="B"> B</option>
          <option value="C"> C</option>
            </select> <br>

            <div class="control-group" id="showA" style="display:none;">
            <select name="client_orderid" id="options2" onchange="showTextNature()">
              <option value="blue"> blue</option>
              <option value="green"> green</option>
              <option value="yellow"> yellow</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group" id="showB" style="display:none;">
            <select name="client_orderid" id="options3" onchange="showTextAnimal()">
              <option value="sun"> sun</option>
              <option value="sky"> sky</option>
              <option value="tree"> tree</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group" id="showC" style="display:none;">
            <select name="client_orderid" id="options4" onchange="showText()">
              <option value="dog"> dog</option>
              <option value="cat"> cat</option>
              <option value="fish"> fish</option>
            </select>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fqzturn4/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, pass the value selected to the function:

```
<select name="client_orderid" id="options" onchange="showText(this.value)">
```

Then, in the function, show or hide the appropriate div based on the value matching the element ID (I presume "A" should match "showA" and so on):

```
function showText(value) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.controls .control-group');
    var re = new RegExp( value + '$');

    for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      elements[i].style.display = re.test(elements[i].id)? '' : 'none';
    }
}
```

*showText* should only be used on the first select, not the others unless there is some logic that you haven't explained.